# li text doesn't appear when I add class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a li element to a ul.

Code for ul:

```
<ul id="issueUserList" class="list-group"></ul>
```

When I add a li without a class something like this:

```
function () {
   var $issueUserList = $("#issueUserList");
   $('<li></li>',
            {
                text: $("#formEmail :selected").text()
            })
            .appendTo($issueUserList);
});
```

This works fine, but when i add a class at li something like:

```
<li class="list-group-item"></li>
```

The text no longer appears

Comment: Is it a typo? `<li class="list-group-item"</li>` missing `>`

Comment: sorry like i said bellow i just missed that when typing the code doesnt have that typo, apologies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `class` property.Please try this:

```
 var $issueUserList = $("#issueUserList");
 $('<li></li>',
 {
      class:"list-group-item",
      text: $("#formEmail :selected").text()
 })
 .appendTo($issueUserList);
```

```js
$('button').click(function(){
 var $issueUserList = $("#issueUserList");
            $('<li></li>',
            {
                class:"list-group-item",
                text: $("#formEmail :selected").text()
            })
            .appendTo($issueUserList);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="issueUserList" class="list-group"></ul>
<select id="formEmail">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
<button>Click</button>
```

Comment: Yes this one worked! Thanks i tough you can't do that! i will mark as correct when stackoveflow time allows me!

Comment: Yes i will stackoverflow doesn't let you do it in the first 15 mins your question has been psoted!

Answer (score 2):

Add class in options:

```
$('<li></li>',
        {
            class: "list-group-item",
            text: $("#formEmail :selected").text(),
        })
        .appendTo($issueUserList);
```

working example: https://jsfiddle.net/3xxcofo7/

Answer (score 1):

Try put class in option parameter.

See:

```
function () {
   var $issueUserList = $("#issueUserList");
   $('<li></li>',
            {
                text: $("#formEmail :selected").text(),
                class: 'list-group-item'
            })
            .appendTo($issueUserList);
});
```